# connecting pgadmin container and postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

using UBUNTO OS 
have downloaded the postgres and pgadmin images and ran the containers

postgres command
**sudo docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XYZ_PW -p 5432:5432  -d postgres**

pgadmin command
**sudo docker run --name pgadmin --link some-postgres:postgres -p 80:80 -d fenglc/pgadmin4**

then ensured that both the containers are running like below

```
sudo docker container ls 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
3bf1e2bcf5e7   fenglc/pgadmin4   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 5050/tcp   pgadmin
b21c2bda2cff   postgres          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago       Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp     some-postgres
```

now issue is when trying to access pgadmin @ localhost/ or localhost:80
it is showing connection reset error
[image: error accessing pgadmin]

also below is the result of docker inspect pgadmin

> "NetworkSettings": {
> "Bridge": "",
> "SandboxID": "fb4f3dcf1eed267055060b945ba8fb4bff372873d1cc179a24c934c883c1d100",
> "HairpinMode": false,
> "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
> "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
> "Ports": {
> "5050/tcp": null,
> "80/tcp": [
> {
> "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
> "HostPort": "80"
> },
> {
> "HostIp": "::",
> "HostPort": "80"
> }
> ]
> },
> "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/fb4f3dcf1eed",
> "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
> "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
> "EndpointID": "879f386a86712d2699373ef8667b07984db337e7267a2381da69cdbc5405251e",
> "Gateway": "XXXX.XX.0.1",
> "GlobalIPv6Address": "",

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fengic/pgadmin4 listens on port 5050. Not on port 80. So your `docker run` command needs to be

```
sudo docker run --name pgadmin --link some-postgres:postgres -p 80:5050 -d fenglc/pgadmin4
```

Then you should be able to access pgadmin on localhost port 80.

Be aware that links are an outdated way of connecting containers and the feature may be removed at some point. The recommended way to connect containers is using docker networks.